# Using f.select for year drop down default to current year in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I am using drop down for selecting year in my form. How do I make my drop down defaults to current year. By using select_year method, we can use like

`<%= select_year (Date.today, start_year: Date.today.year-1, end_year: Date.today.year+1) %>`

Similarly how do I use it my form_for?

```
<%= i.select :year, (Date.today.year-1)..(Date.today.year+1), :selected => Date.today.year %>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
<%= i.select :year, (Date.today.year-1)..(Date.today.year+1), :selected => Time.current.year %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
<% year = Date.today.year %>
<%= i.select :year, options_for_selection((year-1)..(year+1), year)  %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your try @hoangdd. It throws undefined method 'year' error.

Comment: I set `year` is this year. I don't understand why you got error. Sorry about that.